# Div loading outside form on mobile

Tags: html, templates, web

I have a div inside a form that is loading within the form on desktop but jumps out of the form tag when it is loaded on mobile. here is the code:

```
    <div class="small-12 medium-5 large-3 columns end">
            <form id="video-filter" class="video-filter" method="post">
                <h2>Filter by</h2>
                <div class="select-videospage">
                    <label for="sort" class="select-wrapper select-dark select-dark--videos">
                        <select name="filterby">
                            <option value="new">Most recent</option>
                            <option value="views">Most viewed</option>
                            <option value="likes">Most liked</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label for="sort" class="select-wrapper select-dark--time">
                        <select name="time">
                            <option value="all">All</option>
                            <option value="week">Weekly</option>
                            <option value="month">Monthly</option>
                            <option value="year">Yearly</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="video-filter__choosen">
                    <ul>
                        <!-- checkbox values will be appended here -->
                    </ul>
                    <button id="clear">Clear all</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

The div that is loading outside of the form is "select-videospage". I cant figure out why the template would load differently on the two.

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing the css too

Comment: would the css effect where the element loads in the template?

Comment: yes, it depends on css position attribute for example